# asset('assets') return to wrong directory after using prefix in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, routes, assets, prefix

This is the line I load my assets:

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets') }}/js/vendors/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

And here code from `web.php` for route settings:

```
Route::resource('masuk', 'Backend\ParkirInController');
```

It works fine with this code, but when I using a prefix like here:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'parkir'], function (){
   Route::resource('masuk', 'Backend\ParkirInController');
});
```

The assets are not loaded and show an error like

> require.min.js:5 GET http://localhost:8000/parkir/assets/js/vendors/jquery-3.2.1.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

So the name of prefix `parkir` is included to the assets URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can solve it! This is because the `dashboard.js` from template is using `require.js` to set the required assets with a static path.
It look like this
[Static path of assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7xrr.png)

After I added `/` at the beginning of line like what @Imran said. It works fine

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

`<script src="{{ asset('assets') }}/js/vendors/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`

to

`<script src="{{ asset('/assets/js/vendors/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>`

Here, you have just added a `/` before the `assets` so that the url starts from root instead of relative current path.

Comment: Still got an error. here some screenshots, this is the error, https://ibb.co/ZWhsN8L 
 and this is the url https://ibb.co/dm4VY70

Comment: and this is what i got whe try to {{dd(asset('/assets/js/vendors/Datatables-1.10.19/jquery.dataTables.min.js'))}} "http://localhost:8000/assets/js/vendors/Datatables-1.10.19/jquery.dataTables.min.js" @Imran